# Can still select from JComboBox after being disabled

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, tablecellrenderer

Im having problems setting up a JComboBox. The user is given a few options on a separte panel which determine if a JComboBox should be enabled/disabled - the problem I have is that the user can still select from the JComboBox even when it is disabled (It's disabled as the combobox is greyed out)! The JComboBox uses a custom TableCellRenderer and custom DefaultCellEditor. Also the JComboBox is a cell/column in a row of a JTable.

So here is a breakdown of the code:

**prepareRenderer of the JTable********

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
    JComponent component = (JComponent) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
       //Code which checks to see if component should be enabled
       enableComponent = false;
       component.setEnabled(enableComponent);
    }
```

*Set up the combobox *

```
public void setupUserCombo(){

       TableColumn col = getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
           List<String> comboUsers = new String["Adam", "Ben"]

    MyComboBoxRenderer jComboBox = (new MyComboBoxRenderer((String[])values.toArray(comboUsers ));
    col.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor((String[])values.toArray(new String[0])));
    col.setCellRenderer(jComboBox);

    repaint();
}
```

*TableCellRenderer *

```
    public class MyComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyComboBoxRenderer(String[] items) {
        super(items);
        repaint();
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setSelectedItem("");

        if (isSelected) {
            super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }

        setSelectedItem(value);

        return this;
    }

}
```

*DefaultCellEditor *

```
    public class MyComboBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyComboBoxEditor(String[] items) {
        super(new JComboBox(items));
    }
}
```

Any pointers as to what im doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disabled the edition of a cell in a table, you should override [`TableModel.isCellEditable(int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29)

Here all you are doing is render a disabled JComboBox but this does not prevent edition, it just renders a disabled JComboBox. See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender

Comment: Excellent - thanks for the help! The problem was i was already overriding that method in the model to always return true if the combobox was selected. Now fixed to only return true if its enabled.

Answer (score 2):

- see [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) about [Using a Combo Box as an Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox)
- [view by @aterai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12844115/714968)
- don't store `JComponents` in the `XxxTableModel`, then last selected value from `JComboBox` is stored in `XxxTableModel` as `String value`